# Active Directory Change Webpage field using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am currently trying to figure out how to change the web page field in Active Directory using Powershell! I have found out how to change every other field but no where says how to change that field! (example: http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/powershell-tutorial-active-directory/)

I am currently using `Set-User -Identity 'xxxxxxxxxx' -Description 'xxxxxxxx' -Office 'xxxxxxxx' -telephoneNumber 'xxxxxxxxx' -email 'xxxxxxxx'  -StreetAddress 'xxxxxxxxx' -City 'xxxxxxxx' -StateOrProvince 'xx' -PostalCode 'xxxxxx' -country 'United States'`

I have highlighted the field I am trying to change. Thanks for the help everyone!

[image: AD Field]

Comment: Maybe include an example of how you changed the other fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Set-ADUser -HomePage http://www.google.com -Identity username
```

Comment: Does it have to be set-ADUser or can it just be Set-user?

Comment: Set-ADUser is the Microsoft cmdlet that comes with the ActiveDirectory module.